# Relationship between 2 collections Arangodb

Tags: python, nosql, arangodb, aql, pyarango

I have 2 collections :

- User
- Tweet

I want store in User the list of tweet_id and in each tweet the user_id. In my json Tweets files I have the tweet author champ.I try with AQL but I did not succeed, can you help me ?

Thanks

ps: I'm French student sorry for this broken English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have User documents like:

```
{
  "_key": "1234",
  "name": "John"
}
```

And Tweet documents like:

```
{
  "_key": "56789",
  "message": "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet",
  "author": "1234"
}
```

Then you could use the following AQL query:

```
FOR tweet IN Tweet
  UPDATE tweet.author WITH { tweet_key: tweet._key } IN User
  RETURN NEW
```

It iterates over all documents in Tweet collection and tries to update documents in User collection based on the attribute value `author`, which must be identical to the document key in User. It adds the document key of the Tweet document as a new attribute to the User document.

If you didn't make the User ID and Tweet ID the document keys of the respective collections, then you have to use a different query. Let's assume User documents like:

```
{
  "_key": "376472856",
  "user_id": 1234,
  "name": "John"
}
```

And Tweet documents like:

```
{
  "_key": "8975438957",
  "tweet_id": 56789,
  "message": "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet",
  "author": 1234
}
```

Then you should create a hash index (possibly unique) in User collection on field `user_id` and run the following query:

```
FOR tweet IN Tweet
  FOR user IN User
    FILTER user.user_id == tweet.author
    LIMIT 1
    UPDATE user WITH { tweet_id: tweet.tweet_id } IN User
    RETURN NEW
```

It will augment User documents with an attribute tweet_id equal to the tweet_id attribute in the corresponding Tweet document.

Comment: perfect Thanks for your help